# Embedding Zoho ASAP into website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, zoho

I'm currently attempting to embed Zoho's ASAP function into our company website, while testing the script I've ran into nothing but problems (notably because my knowledge of JavaScript is quite poor)

Here's the code snippit of the script, this script is within the header tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 window.ZohoHCAsap=window.ZohoHCAsap||function(a,b){ZohoHCAsap[a]=b;};
 (function(){
  var d=document;
  var s=d.createElement("script");
  s.type="text/javascript";
  s.defer=true;
  s.src="https://desk.zoho.com/portal/api/web/inapp/168138000006546086?orgId=XXX_XXX_XXX_XXX";
  d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
 })();
</script>
```

Of course orgId is redacted for privacy reasons.

I've created an iframe in the body to call the script when the page loads with:

```
<iframe id="zsAsapFrame" width="1000" height="1000" name="zsAsapFrame" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="false" frameborder="0" border="0" src="https://desk.zoho.com/portal/api/web/inapp/168138000006546086?orgId=XXX_XXX_XXX"></iframe>
```

As far as my untrained eye can see, this shouldn't produce an issue, however it does. This is the result of me opening the file in a browser:

[This is the output on the website I get, private information redacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0PdP.png)

What I'm trying to figure out here is where I'm making this mistake and what it is that's stopping me from getting this script working.

---

**Update:** I have since realised that my fault was a simple fix and this could provide useful for future users when ASAP gets a full release.

What I was attempting to do was test this script within a locally hosted HTML file, however due to the nature of the script being linked to a website, it won't function correctly unless integrated into a page on your own website. My advice is create a non indexed page to use for testing. The iframe is not needed as the script function given just calls to an external script that fills in the blanks itself.

In no longer need assistance in getting this script running, however the post may be useful to a future developer who runs into the same issue during testing of this feature.